# Proof of Theorem 23.2 in Jech' Set Theory (The third millenium edition)

Tags: set-theory

I was reviewing proof of Theorem 23.2 in Jech' set theory book, theorem which he attributes to Gregory.
In the course of the proof Jech defines the set C "of all $\alpha < \kappa^{+}$ such that for every $\beta < \alpha$, $X \cap \beta = x_{\gamma}$ for some $\gamma < \alpha$". Here X designates any subset of $\kappa^{+}$, and the $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa^{+}}$ are an enumeration of all bounded subsets of $\kappa^{+}$ (which is possible since we assume $2^{\kappa} = \kappa^{+}$).
Jech asserts that C is a club. I can see why it is closed, however I have a hard time coming up with a straightforward argument showing that C is unbounded. My idea is that by contradiction we could build a $\kappa$ -sequence cofinal in $\kappa^{+}$, which would contradict the regularity of $\kappa^{+}$, but I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Any help would be very much appreciated (just giving the idea, not a detailed proof), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from a standard closure argument. Fix $\alpha_0<\kappa^+$, and define $\alpha_n$ inductively as follows: For each $\xi<\alpha_n$, choose a minimal $\gamma_\xi$ such that $X\cap \xi= x_{\gamma_\xi}$, and set $\alpha_{n+1}=\sup \{\gamma_\xi\mid \xi<\alpha_n\}$. Then take $\alpha_\omega=\sup_n\alpha_n$.

---

In general, if $\kappa$ is regular and $f\colon \kappa\to\kappa$, then $C=\{\alpha<\kappa \mid f\upharpoonright\alpha \colon\alpha\to\alpha\}$ is a club, and the above theorem is a special case of this general result (when we take $f(\xi)=\gamma_\xi$.)